# Turn off prompt when saving file in emacs

Tags: emacs

How can I turn off the prompt when I try to save the file in Emacs?

I mean every time I do <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>s</kbd>, emacs always ask "Save file xxx?"

How can I disable this prompt?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You're looking for the command <kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>C-s</kbd> (keep holding control when you hit the "s"). That doesn't prompt before save.

Comment: @lydonchandra- `C-x s` (what you had been using) attempts to save *all* files and buffers while ivarley's recommendation is just for the current file/buffer.

Comment: @RayVega yeah.. C-u C-x s   would save all without prompting